# Workflow status remains 'In Progress'

Tags: 2010, designer-workflow

I have a simple workflow that looks for a date in a list (Target date) and sets the 'Acknowledged Target Date' to 5 days after the 'Received date'. It then creates a task for the Complaints Administrator, once the task is complete it sets 'Complaint date' to 'Today'. See the workflow steps below.

The problem we sometimes have is that the workflow status remains 'In Progress', for a day or two, even though the 'Acknowledged Target Date' is set and the task is completed by the user. This doesn't happen every time.

Set **Acknowledged Target Date (workflow)** to **Target date:5 days**

then Start **Acknowledge Complaint** process on **Current Item** with **Complaint Administrator**

then Set **Complaint Date (workflow)** to **Today**

Answer (score 0):

try to end/stop workflow through the actions. though not correct approach but will work.